# ios enable location services and show closest city immediately after

Tags: ios, geolocation, cllocationmanager, cllocation, location-services

I am using `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` for my app, and I want to do the following.

After the user signs up, I show a soft prompt, asking the user if they will give the app access to their location. If they click yes, I then call:

```
 if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
      [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
 }
```

This results in the ios prompt asking the user to enable location services for the app. If the user clicks `YES` I want to grab their current location, and if their current location is close to one of the cities that my app is live in I will simply return to the app.

However, if the city is not close to any of the cities that my app is live in, I want to show a screen showing a list of the cities avail and ask them to choose one. What I am doing currently is I wait on the given page until the `locationManager:didUpdateLocations` callback fires so that I have a current location. Then I do the necessary checking to see if that city is close to one of my serviceable cities or not.

The issue I am having is that sometimes the  callback doesn't fire right away and the user will then be stuck on the prompt page with nothing happening. What is the right way to do this?

To note, I don't care about exact location -- just need the general vicinity of the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges
```

Is used to track changes in location but only when they are moving around. What you describe isn't necessarily the same. If I open your app and stand still there is no 'significant location change' to fire the methods.

From Apple docs

> After returning a current location fix, the receiver generates update events **only when a significant change in the user’s location is detected**.

I would change from passive 'significant' to this

```
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: is the current location for the app not set to nil though in the location manager? if i did [locationManager location] would that return a nil value?

Comment: This comments is not clear.Start updating location means the app is tracing device coordinates (purple location icon visible). When you have your coordinate you can stop the location manager from obtaining further location updates by stopping it. Is this what you need?

Comment: My point is that if the location manager's current known location is nil, then even just standing there should result in a location change callback, correct?

Comment: No that's not it's intended use. It won't treat the differences between nil and a long lat location as a significant location change. If you think about it, to test to see if a device is moving it would need to test 2 sets of coordinates. nil isn't a coordinate it can compare from.

Comment: Then can you explain why, on the simulator, when I start off the debugger with "No location" (and I verified that the location is nil at this point for the location manager), and then I switch it to San Francisco, the callback is fired?

Comment: A simulator is just that. By switching to San Fran you are 'pretending to locate there'. On a real device you would have to teleport to effect the same. Trust me I have done this 100 times. You could have changed your code by now. If you swap the call as I said earlier you will be fine. If you need me to show more code forget 'significant' and use the correct approach.

Comment: I want to use significant as opposed to constantly updating. I don't need that many updates. Also, if you read your original comment: you need two coordinates, and nil isnt a coordinate to compare from. So you just negated what you first said in that comment...doesn't matter if i teleported to SF or not, point is the original set of coordinates is nil, so by your own logic the significant changes should not have recorded that as a change.

Comment: Your missing the point. When you get your update you stop location manager. If you want to convince your self that because you can teleport in the simulator its the correct approach, go ahead. But unless you can teleport in real life you are not really testing for a real situation. Good luck with making it work

Comment: I don't want to continue this convo,but the point I am making is that you cited an incorrect reason to me. "If you think about it, to test to see if a device is moving it would need to test 2 sets of coords. nil isn't a coord it can compare from." That's clearly wrong if the simulator records a change btwn nil and SF. As for a real solution, I figured out that sig location doesnt fire it as a change, but it loads up the initial location still. I can just plug into the authStatusChanged callback and check to see if the status changed to approved. Then I can directly access the initial location.

Comment: You clearly can't read documentation. After returning a current location fix, the receiver generates update events only when a significant change in the user’s location is detected. I hope you give your users a nice waiting screen. Maybe a label explaining that they have to walk around a bit to continue or teleport to San Fran to continue. Good luck with marking down a comment.

Comment: Lol at the hostility. Again, you said comparing nil to a real coordinate wouldnt register as a significant change. You are 100% wrong on that -- not sure why you're trying to argue with me on points I am not even making. Take care bud!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63623/discussion-between-latenitecoder-and-atul-bhatia).